# How to git commit --amend a commit that's the base of a branch

Tags: git, rebase, git-amend

I have branch foo off of master/head.  I wanted to ammend the master/head and have these changes picked up on branch foo.  I did the following:

```
git checkout master
git add ...
git commit --amend
git checkout foo
git rebase master
```

The problem was the old non-amended commit shows up as part of branch foo after the amend, and it got rebased onto master.  I did a git rebase -i and deleted the old commit and that worked, but is there an easier/safer way to modify the commit that's the base of a branch?  And yes, it's all local commits that haven't been pushed..

Answer (score 28, accepted):

All you needed to do was to tell git where to start the rebase from: You can do this

```
git rebase --onto master SOMESHA foo
```

Where SOMESHA is the old master SHA. That is if your tree now looks like this

```
* aaaaaa - (master)
| * bbbbbb - (foo)
| * cccccc - (old master)
|/  
* ffffff
```

And you do

```
git rebase --onto master cccccc foo
```

Your tree will then look like this.

```
* dddddd - (foo)
|
* aaaaaa - (master)
|
* ffffff
```

**ASIDE:** we can use different names for the `cccccc` commit if you dont like using SHA values.

```
> git reflog master

aaaaaa master@{0}: reset: moving to something
cccccc master@{1}: commit: change the froozle
ffffff master@{2}: commit: snarf the froozle
```

This means we can reference `cccccc` as `master@{1}` (AKA, the previous location of master)

So we could write this rebase as

```
git rebase --onto master master@{1} foo
```

Another description of the commit `cccccc` is `foo^` (AKA, the parernt commit for foo), so we could also write this as

```
git rebase --onto master foo^ foo
```

They all do exactly the same thing, and you may prefer to use different ones in different situations. I usually find the SHA simple to use, as I will often pull up a graph of my repository before performing this kind of operation.

Comment: For anyone who wishes to understand what these rebase commands work in detail I can recommand [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32553279/452775).

Comment: I can confirm this solved my problem