# Git rebase arguments context explanation needed

Tags: git, github

Very often `git rebase` used in a context of some branch. For example, if I want to move the base of `feature` branch on top of the `master` branch (based on latest commits) - tutorials say:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master
```

After tutorials like that, there are a lot of questions. Eg: how to perform the same action without checking out. How can I do the same action with `--onto` option. What the difference between `--onto` and just rebase. Can I pass a range of commits or it must be a whole branch? Etc..

I've read man page several times but still have a big gap.

So **the main problem is:** how git parse the args in different scenarios and how should I interpret/imagine them in my head? For example:

```
git rebase master
git rebase feature master
git rebase --onto master feature
git rebase HEAD~4 HEAD~2
git rebase --onto HEAD~4 HEAD~2
```

Let's assume we have the following repo:

```
Z -- W (HEAD, test-branch*) 

A -- B -- C -- D -- E (master)
     \
      1 -- 2 -- 3 (feature)

test-branch is checked out.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The full rebase command is this.

```
git rebase --onto <onto> <upstream> <branch-to-rebase>
```

Git will take all the changes in `branch-to-rebase` which are not in `upstream` and put them on top of `onto`.

The defaults are...

- *branch-to-rebase*: current branch
- *upstream*: branch-to-rebase's tracking branch
- *onto*: upstream

`git checkout feature; git rebase master` is really `git rebase --onto master master feature`.

You generally want `onto` and `upstream` to be the same, but sometimes it's useful for them to be different for delicate surgery. The difference between `upstream` and `onto` is made clear in this example.

```
           A--B--C--D master
               \
                E--F--G next
                       \
                        H--I--J topic
```

If you `git rebase master topic`, it will rebase all the commits that `topic` does not have in common with `master`. All intervening branch heads will be ignored. That is E, F, G, H, I and J. Since `onto` defaults to `upstream`, it will put those on `master`. You'll wind up with this.

```
           A--B--C--D master
               \     \
                \     E'-F'-G'-H'-I'-J' topic
                 \
                  E--F--G next
```

What if you just want the commits from `next` to `topic`?  This is where `--onto` becomes useful. Tell Git that the upstream is `next`, but you want to rebase onto `master`. So run `git rebase --onto master next topic`.  This will select just H, I and J.

```
           A--B--C--D master
               \     \
                \     H'-I'-J' topic
                 \
                  E--F--G next
```

Comment: Very good! I need to read it carefully. Could you explain what is `upstream` in this context mean? I tried to translate this word, but got nothing useful..

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov `upstream` is what a branch branched from. `upstream` like moving up a river against the current. The current here is time. If you start walking back through the history of branch towards another branch you're going `upstream`. In my examples, `master` is upstream from `topic`. What it means for rebase is Git will take all the changes in `branch-to-rebase` which are not in `upstream` and put them on top of `onto`.

Answer (score 1):

[`git rebase` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

- `git rebase master` rebases the current branch on top of `master` (meaning `master` is checked out, and the current branch is reset to `master`, its commits are rebased on top of it).

Considering the current branch is test-branch:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- Z' -- W' (test-branch)
                 (master)
```

- `git rebase feature master` replays `master` commits on top of `feature` (rare, the best practice is to do the opposite)

That is:

```
A -- B
      \
       1 -- 2 -- 3 -- C' -- D' -- E' (master)
              (feature)
```

- `git rebase --onto master feature` would move all commits after feature up to the current branch on top of the new base `master`.
  Since `feature` and `test-branch` are not related, that wouldn't move any commit.
- `git rebase HEAD~4 HEAD~2` reset the current branch to `@~2`

For a `test-branch` like `Z -- Y -- X -- W`, that would mean `Z -- Y`

- `git rebase --onto HEAD~4 HEAD~2` would remove `@~3` and `@~2` from the current branch since it replay all commit from *after* `@~2` (that is `@~1` and `@`) onto the new base `@~4`.

Comment: Unfortunately @VonC, but I didn't get the idea in you examples starting from 2nd one. I just can't imagine what's going on without schemas( I would be very grateful if you give schemas like in first example.

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov I have only added a diagram for the second case.